# How to avoid service dependencies from being stopped in Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

Given the following Docker Compose file....

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  producer:
    image: producer
    container_name: producer
    depends_on: [db]
    build:
      context: ./producer
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile

  db:
    image: some-db-image
    container_name: db
```

When I do `docker-compose up producer` obviously the `db` service gets started too. When I `CTRL+C` both services are stopped. This is expected and fine.

But sometimes, the `db` service is started before, on a different shell and so doing `docker-compose up producer` understands that `db` is running and only starts `producer`. But when I hit `CTRL+C`, both `producer` and `db` are stopped even though `db` was not started as part of this `docker compose up` command.

Is there a way to avoid getting the dependencies services stopped when stopping its "parent" ?

Comment: I agree with the answers, you should detach and use stop service, but could be possible that this is a bug, you should post an issue related to this https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/1571

Answer (score 0):

When running just `docker-compose up`, the `CTRL+C` command always stops all running services in the current compose scope. It doesn't care about `depends_on`.

You would need to spin it up with detach option `-d`, like

```
docker-compose up -d producer
```

Then you can do

```
docker stop producer
```

And db service should still be running.

Comment: I'm not running `docker-compose up`, I always run `docker-compose up service`. So if I just "upped" the `producer` service, CTRL+C should only stop the `producer` service. But it also stops all the services that producer depends on. I think that's confusing.

Detached is not an option because I do want to see the output on another shell.

Comment: You're right, it is somehow confusing. I don't think there's a way, to achieve exactly what you want to do. As I said, CTRL+C stops all the running services in your compose file, not just the services your upped service depends on.

Comment: alternatively, for seeing the output: you can detach and after that 
docker logs producer -f   (to follow logs again)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question: You want to stop a container A which depends on another container B. But when stopping A, you don't want docker-compose to stop B.

Docker-compose stops the dependent containers ('B' in this case) when 'A' is stopped.

How I would approach this:

1. Split up the docker-compose files into A and B
2. In docker-compose for A create a health check testing (and waiting) for container B to be alive.
   Since this is a database, you could do this with a dummy query.

Then you still have dependency, but not the docker-compose connection of stopping dependant containers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply do that with `CTRL+C`.

Your docker-compose file and the services defined in it are treated as a [project](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name). You may notice that all containers, networks and volumes are prefixed with the name of the directory where the docker-compose file is located by default. This is the project name. It can be changed via an environment variable or the [`-p` flag](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) of the `docker-compose` command.
What `docker-compose` does is it keeps track of all the resources for a given project.

In your case there are two services: `db` and `producer`. Whenever you run `docker-compose up`, both of them start up. They both end up being part of the same project. The same applies when you only start one of the services (e.g. with `docker-compose up db`). You can later start the other service and it will still be part of the same project.

**One more thing to note here:** Whenever you run `docker-compose` without the `-d` (detached) flag, you get attached to the **whole** project, meaning whenever you hit `CTRL+C`, you'll stop all services. It does not matter if the last compose command started only one of the services or if they depend on each other. Attaching to the project and hitting `CTRL+C` will stop them.

A possible solution to your problem would be the following:
Start up your services via `docker-compose up -d` (both `db` and `producer` will get created). They are now in detached mode. If you still want to check the logs in real time (kinda like attaching), use `docker-compose logs -f`. Now, however, if you want to stop only one of the services you can simply do `docker-compose stop $SVC_NAME` (where $SVC_NAME is either `db` or `producer`) and this will keep the other one running. This way, whatever happens to your terminal session, your services won't stop, unless you explicitly tell them to.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to avoid getting the dependencies services stopped when stopping its "parent" ?

Yes.
Using the new version `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose` might solve your problem [Reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#compose-v2-and-the-new-docker-compose-command).

### Simple example

Assuming now you are using the new version, your process could be something like this.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    build: .
  producer:
    build: .
    depends_on: [db]
  extra:
    build: .
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "script.sh" ]
```

**script.sh**

```
while :; do sleep 1; done
```

Suppose `db` has started before with
`$ docker compose up -d db`.
Then later,
`$ docker compose up -d producer`.
Now you can stop only `producer` with
`$ docker compose stop producer`.
You can check if `db` is still running with
`$ docker compose ps`.

Notice the use of `-d` flag for *detached* mode, as pointed out in another answer, so you don't need to kill the process with `CTRL+C`. Also, using detached flag allows you to check the services that are running with `docker compose ps`.

A similar issue as yours was reported and fixed a while ago, as you can see [here](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/pull/1577).

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce the behavior you observe with a complete minimal example. Namely, when running `docker compose stop producer`, the underlying `db` is not stopped AFAICT.

Anyway, you may be interested in an alternative command that is a bit more flexible than `docker compose up`, regarding how to run "one-off commands": [`docker compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/).

The typical use cases are as follows:

- `docker compose run db bash` → run the `db` service, replacing the default `CMD` with `bash`
- `docker compose run -d db` → run the `db` service in the background (detach mode)
- `docker compose run --service-ports producer` → run the service `producer` *and its dependencies* (unless they were run with `docker compose up`), enabling the ports mapping.

So for your specific use case, you could run:

```bash
docker compose up -d db

docker compose run --service-ports producer
```

Comment: “When I CTRL+C”